Wixsharp MSI installation
new Dir(new Id("WEBROOTPATH"),
        new Dir("Service"),
        //new IISWebSite(new Id("WEBSITENAME"), 80),
        new IISVirtualDir
        {
            Name = "WebAPP"
            AppName = "Test2"
            WebSite = new WebSite(new Id("WEBSITENAME"),new Id("WEBPORT")) { InstallWebSite = true },
            WebAppPool = new WebAppPool(new Id("WEBSITENAME"), "Identity=applicationPoolIdentity")
        }));

I want the name of website and port user defined. But the code i have implemented is not supporting it.
It works for creating directory(e.g. WEBROOTPATH).
Is there any alternative way I can implement this?
Wixsharp internally generates .wxs file which is xml file.
Can someone help me with XDocument code for the same?
